# How to call a function from another component on vue

Tags: vue.js, routes

Irm trying to call a function from another component in my vue app.

In my library.vue, I have a function to open a popup with an id :

```
displayPopup(id: String)
```

Dnd on my view, I have a route.param with an ID, and when i call mysite.com/12, I would like to open the 12th popup.

The library component is called in my view.

Do someone have any idea on how to open the popup when i call the good URL ?

Comment: please share more code

Comment: popup... you mean window.open() ? Not seeing any code here.

Answer (score 0):

to call a method placed inside a child component from the parent component you should set a `ref` on child component in the parent like `<child ref="someRef"></child>` then you can access the child methods from the parent component like `this.$refs.someRef.childMethodName()`

here is a link to Vue documentation explaining this behaviour:

[Accessing Child Component Instances & Child Elements](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements)

check out the example below where clicking on a button in the parent component calls a method inside the child component which increments the number displayed in the child component:

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: `<div>number of clicks: {{ num }}</div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      num: 0,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addToNum() {
      this.num++;
    },
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    callChildMethod() {
      this.$refs.child.addToNum();
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="callChildMethod()">click to call addToNum method in child component from parent</button>
  <child ref="child"></child>
  <div>
```

Comment: Khobi? Can you share a source lotfan?

Comment: @KickButtowski I edited the answer and included a link to vue documentation if that's what you've asked for

Answer (score 0):

Are you using composition api? If yes, you can create composable.
example

usePosts.js

```js
async function loadPost(id) {
  const post = await fetchPost(id)
  setPost(post)
}

export {
  loadPost
}
```

component:

```js
<script>
import usePosts from './usePosts'

export default {
  setup () {
    const posts = usePosts()

    posts.loadPost({ id })

    return {
      posts
    }
  }
}
</script>
```